# How is the Font Bold method used in Java?

Tags: java

So,I was trying Java  swing GUI for the first time,and I tried to set the Text from this Label:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
```

To bold with this line:

```
label.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 20));
```

And I get 2 Errors:

```
BOLD cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

and

```
The method setFont(java.awt.Font) in the type JComponent is not applicable for the arguments (javafx.scene.text.Font)
```

Did I write something wrong,or am I using stuff,that isn't supported in that class?

Comment: You've imported javafx.scene.text.Font delete that import statement and make sure you're using java.awt.Font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `import` statements. You or your IDE has accidentally imported a different Font class.

With Swing you want:

```
java.awt.Font
```

Not:

```
javafx.scene.text.Font
```

Comment: OMG Thank You!That worked,I ended up deleting the import javafx.scene.text.Font and it worked!